# What happens if multiple host on a local network share the same username

Tags: ssh

Something I find odd about ssh-ing into a device remotely is how multiple devices on my home network share the same public IP. In theory multiple hosts could have the same username so when I go `ssh admin@123.1.1.2` imaginably multiple computers on my network could have a user called `admin`.

So when I do ssh into admin how does SSH figure out which host on my local network to connect to? Can all of them even listen?

Answer (score 3):

the username has nothing to do with it, each computer has an independent username/password database.

Whatever device has 123.1.1.2 as an IP address will have to forward the ssh port to the specified internal IP address.  One port can only be mapped to 1 internal IP.

So port 22 could be forwarded to 192.168.0.1

If you want to reach a second computer, you would have to setup a different port.

So port 23 could be forward to 192.168.0.2 for example.

However, port 25 is typically used for email servers so if your running one you can't use this port.

However, this is generally a bad security practice exposing your computers to the internet this way.

Generally, the preferred way is to use a VPN.  Then connect through the VPN to your internal network.

Answer (score 0):

Only one device has the public IP.  The public IP is that of the public facing network interface of your router (or whatever edge/gateway device you use) and NOT each of your interal devices.  You have to set up forwarding rules on that edge device in order to send the incoming traffic to the write internal host.  This happens at the network/transport level, transparently to ssh.

Comment: This does not really seem to answer the question.

Comment: How not?  Forwarding rules on the edge device is how it is determined.

Comment: Yes, but OP asks about the same usernames to connect to a host, which your answer does not mention at all. True, its irrelevent for the answer, but that should be adressed like happened in the other answer. For example, I ask the question: I am unable to give my grass water, and now it turns yellow. Why is my grass turning Yellow? You answer: Grass needs water to survive. My response: Yes, I already told you that I cannot. Why is it turning yellow though? The correct answer is: Your grass turning yellow means that it is dying. Grass needs water to survive.

Comment: I don't disagree with what you're explaining, but it's hardly an explanation of why my answer doesn't fit the question.  It answers the question just fine, if not as well as another.

Comment: The question is "**What happens** if multiple host on a local network **share the same username**?" tell me where in the answer this is answered.